# Set function to make newly added class to fade out

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to make a div (load) disappear by adding class "waa" styles to it, the code works but I am trying to add an animation where it fades out rather than close instantly. Is this possible? I have tried to add the transition element and fade out affect but none of them do anything to the class "waa".

```
<style class="INLINE_PEN_STYLESHEET_ID">
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
family=Quattrocento+Sans);
.loading {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: #000;
z-index: 9999;
display:block;

transition: visibility 0s 2s, opacity 2s linear;
}

.loading-text {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin: auto;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
line-height: 100px;
}
.loading-text span {
display: inline-block;
margin: 0 5px;
color: #fff;
font-family: "Quattrocento Sans", sans-serif;
}
.loading-text span:nth-child(1) {
filter: blur(0px);
-webkit-animation: blur-text 1.5s 0s infinite linear alternate;
      animation: blur-text 1.5s 0s infinite linear alternate;
}
.loading-text span:nth-child(2) {
filter: blur(0px);
-webkit-animation: blur-text 1.5s 0.2s infinite linear alternate;
      animation: blur-text 1.5s 0.2s infinite linear alternate;
}
.loading-text span:nth-child(3) {
 filter: blur(0px);
-webkit-animation: blur-text 1.5s 0.4s infinite linear alternate;
      animation: blur-text 1.5s 0.4s infinite linear alternate;
}
.loading-text span:nth-child(4) {
filter: blur(0px);
-webkit-animation: blur-text 1.5s 0.6s infinite linear alternate;
      animation: blur-text 1.5s 0.6s infinite linear alternate;
}
.loading-text span:nth-child(5) {
filter: blur(0px);
-webkit-animation: blur-text 1.5s 0.8s infinite linear alternate;
      animation: blur-text 1.5s 0.8s infinite linear alternate;
}
.loading-text span:nth-child(6) {
filter: blur(0px);
-webkit-animation: blur-text 1.5s 1s infinite linear alternate;
      animation: blur-text 1.5s 1s infinite linear alternate;
}
.loading-text span:nth-child(7) {
filter: blur(0px);
-webkit-animation: blur-text 1.5s 1.2s infinite linear alternate;
      animation: blur-text 1.5s 1.2s infinite linear alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes blur-text {
0% {
filter: blur(0px);
}
100% {
filter: blur(4px);
}
}

@keyframes blur-text {
0% {
filter: blur(0px);
}
100% {
filter: blur(4px);
}
}

}
.waa {
opacity: 0;
transition: opacity 3s;
}

</style>
<div class="loading" id="load">
<div class="loading-text">
    <span class="loading-text-words">L</span>
    <span class="loading-text-words">o</span>
    <span class="loading-text-words">a</span>
    <span class="loading-text-words">d</span>
    <span class="loading-text-words">i</span>
    <span class="loading-text-words">n</span>
    <span class="loading-text-words">g</span>

<div><span style="color:#fff;">made by ASN</span></div> 
</div>
</div>

<script>
setTimeout(function(){
document.getElementById('load').className = 'waa';
}, 4000);
</script>
```

Comment: If the question is about the animation, not the transition, please add the [mcve] of that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css animations to do that

```
@keyframes fadeIn{
   from{
        opacity : 0;
   } 
   to{
        opacity : 1;
    } 
}
.waa{
    animation: fadeIn 2s forwards;
}
```